# Problems with a diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, labels

I am trying to sketch a diagram and I did my best and created the below figure. As you can see from the figure the labels are confusing. Is it possible to fix this problem? Precisely is it possible to label the edges inside of the arrows or along the arrows in the direction of the arrow?

Thanks in advance[image]

Here are the codes:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
        draw, align=center,
        top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
    root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
    env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
    dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5.2cm,
    semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=yellow,draw=none,text=black]
    
    \node[env] (A)                    { $\alpha$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (B) [below left of=A] {Nabla $(q,h)$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (C) [below right of=A] {Delta $(q,h)$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (D) [below of=B] {Nabla $q$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (E) [below left of=B] {Nabla $h$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (F) [below of=C] {Delta $q$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (G) [below right of=C] {Delta $h$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (O) [below left of=F] {Ordinary derivative};
    \node[env]         (H) [left of=A] {$q$-derivative generator};
    \node[env]         (I) [right of=A] {$h$-derivative generator};
    
    
    \path (A) edge              node {$t=0$} (B)
    (A) edge              node {$h\to 0$} (H)
    (A) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (I)
    edge              node {$t=1$} (C)
    (B) edge              node {$h\to 0$} (D)
    (B) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (E)
    (C) edge              node {$h\to 0$} (F)
    (C) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (G)
    (D) edge              node[below] {$q\to 1$} (O)
    (E) edge[thick, bend right]              node[below] {$h\to 0$} (O)
    (F) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (O)
    (G) edge[thick, bend left]              node[below] {$h\to 0$} (O)
    (B) edge              node[left] {$(q,h)\to (1,0)$} (O)
    (C) edge              node[left] {$(q,h)\to (1,0)$} (O)
    (H) edge[thick, bend right]              node[below]{$t=0$} (D)
    (H) edge              node {$t=1$} (F)
    (I) edge[thick, bend left]             node {$t=1$} (G)
    (I) edge [thick, out=90, in=90, looseness=1] node[below] {$t=0$} (E)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you update your post and use a more descriptive title other than something like "I have a problem"?

Answer (score 5):

I think you could also improve it by using a left to right layout, and adjusting the relative positions of the nodes to avoid some crossings.
Like this perhaps:

[image]

I am sure you could do this layout in tikz but here I have used [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) so you need to compile this example with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    pair a, b; a = origin; b = 400 right;
    picture b[];
    b0 = thelabel("\strut $\alpha$-derivative", a);
    b1 = thelabel("\strut Ordinary derivative", b shifted 120 right);
    b2 = thelabel("\strut Delta $h$-derivative", b shifted 80 up);
    b4 = thelabel("\strut Nabla $h$-derivative", b shifted 40 up);
    b3 = thelabel("\strut Delta $q$-derivative", b shifted 40 down);
    b5 = thelabel("\strut Nabla $q$-derivative", b shifted 80 down);
    b6 = thelabel("\strut Delta $(q,h)$-derivative", 7/16[a,b] shifted 24 up);
    b7 = thelabel("\strut Nabla $(q,h)$-derivative", 7/16[a,b] shifted 24 down);
    b8 = thelabel("\strut $h$-derivative generator", 3/8[a,b] shifted 72 up);
    b9 = thelabel("\strut $q$-derivative generator", 3/8[a,b] shifted 72 down);

    forsuffixes $=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9:
        % decorate the box
        interim bboxmargin := 4;
        path corner; corner = 3 up {down} .. {right} 3 right;
        path rb; rb = for i=0 upto 3: corner rotated 90i shifted point i of bbox b$ -- endfor cycle;
        picture fb; fb = image(
        for i = 0 upto 32:
            draw interpath(i/32, subpath(0,1) of bbox b$, subpath (3,2) of bbox b$)
                withpen pencircle scaled 1
                withcolor (i/128+3/4)[blue, white];
        endfor); clip fb to rb; draw fb; draw rb;
        
        % draw the text
        draw b$;
    endfor
    
    vardef connect(expr A, B, r, t) = 
        save s, p; 
        interim bboxmargin := 6;
        path p; p = point 3/2 of bbox A {right} .. {right} point 7/2 of bbox B;
        picture s; s = thelabel(TEX(t) scaled 5/8, point r of p);
        interim bboxmargin := 2; interim ahangle := 30;
        drawarrow p; unfill bbox s; draw s withcolor 2/3 red;
    enddef;

    connect(b0, b6,  1/2, "$t=1$");
    connect(b0, b7,  1/2, "$t=0$");
    connect(b0, b8,  1/2, "$q\to1$");
    connect(b0, b9,  1/2, "$h\to0$");

    connect(b8, b2,  1/3, "$t=1$");
    connect(b8, b4,  1/3, "$t=0$");

    connect(b9, b3,  1/3, "$t=1$");
    connect(b9, b5,  1/3, "$t=0$");

    connect(b6, b1,  9/16, "$(q,h)\to(1,0)$");
    connect(b6, b2,  1/4, "$q\to1$");
    connect(b6, b3,  1/4, "$h\to0$");

    connect(b7, b1,  9/16, "$(q,h)\to(1,0)$");
    connect(b7, b4,  1/4, "$q\to1$");
    connect(b7, b5,  1/4, "$h\to0$");

    vardef connect(expr A, B, r, t) = 
        save s, p; 
        interim bboxmargin := 6;
        path p; p = point 3/2 of bbox A {right} .. {dir -50} point 21/8 of bbox B;
        picture s; s = thelabel(TEX(t) scaled 5/8, point r of p);
        interim bboxmargin := 2; interim ahangle := 30;
        drawarrow p; unfill bbox s; draw s withcolor 2/3 red;
    enddef;
    connect(b2, b1, 1/3, "$h\to0$");
    connect(b4, b1, 1/3, "$h\to0$");

    vardef connect(expr A, B, r, t) = 
        save s, p; 
        interim bboxmargin := 6;
        path p; p = point 3/2 of bbox A {right} .. {dir 50} point 3/8 of bbox B;
        picture s; s = thelabel(TEX(t) scaled 5/8, point r of p);
        interim bboxmargin := 2; interim ahangle := 30;
        drawarrow p; unfill bbox s; draw s withcolor 2/3 red;
    enddef;
    connect(b3, b1, 1/3, "$q\to1$");
    connect(b5, b1, 1/3, "$q\to1$");

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out the "decorate the box" section, you get a plainer version, which I think I prefer:

[image]

Comment: @thurston Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted.  I run your codes in winEdt and faced with several errors. Do I need to load some packages? I am sorry I am not very good at Latex which can be understood from my figure.

Comment: I have just seen this comment "I am sure you could do this layout in tikz but here I have used Metapost so you need to compile this example with lualatex:"

Comment: For tutorials and hints on using Metapost, follow the link that I included at the top.  My example will not compile with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `every node/.append style={sloped}` to your `tikzpicture`. Then some manual adjustments to individual nodes using `below` and `pos=` can clean things up.

Also, note the use of `(H.345)` in the code below. `345` refers to the position (angle) along the perimeter of the node. By not using the default (center) of the node, you can avoid the arrow crossing  the `Nabla (q,h)-derivative` node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
        draw, align=center,
        top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
    root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large, bottom color=red!30},
    env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize},
    dummy/.style    = {circle,draw}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5.2cm,
    semithick, every node/.append style={sloped}]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=yellow,draw=none,text=black]
    
    \node[env] (A)                    { $\alpha$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (B) [below left of=A] {Nabla $(q,h)$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (C) [below right of=A] {Delta $(q,h)$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (D) [below of=B] {Nabla $q$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (E) [below left of=B] {Nabla $h$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (F) [below of=C] {Delta $q$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (G) [below right of=C] {Delta $h$-derivative};
    \node[env]         (O) [below left of=F] {Ordinary derivative};
    \node[env]         (H) [left of=A] {$q$-derivative generator};
    \node[env]         (I) [right of=A] {$h$-derivative generator};
    
    
    \path 
    (A) edge              node {$t=0$} (B)
    (A) edge              node[below, pos=.4] {$h\to 0$} (H)
    (A) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (I)
    edge              node {$t=1$} (C)
    (B) edge              node {$h\to 0$} (D)
    (B) edge              node[pos=.7] {$q\to 1$} (E)
    (C) edge              node {$h\to 0$} (F)
    (C) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (G)
    (D) edge              node[below] {$q\to 1$} (O)
    (E) edge[thick, bend right]              node[below] {$h\to 0$} (O)
    (F) edge              node {$q\to 1$} (O)
    (G) edge[thick, bend left]              node[below] {$h\to 0$} (O)
    (B) edge              node {$(q,h)\to (1,0)$} (O)
    (C) edge              node[pos=.6] {$(q,h)\to (1,0)$} (O)
    (H) edge[thick, bend right]              node[pos=.8]{$t=0$} (D)
    (H.345) edge              node {$t=1$} (F)
    (I) edge[thick, bend left]             node {$t=1$} (G)
    (I) edge [thick, out=90, in=90, looseness=1] node[pos=.4] {$t=0$} (E)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. This works.